# Chrome navbar display issue after full screen video

Tags: google-chrome

I have a Macbook Pro 13" on which i've connected 2 screens.

The issue now is that on Google Chrome, whenever I display a video on full screen, Here's how my navbar looks like :

[image]
That is really annoying and I can't find out how to resolve this... I've reinstalled Chrome but still the same issue.

Thanks